# What happens if a letter of recommendation for a grant contains a mistake about the title of the proposal?

Tags: advisor, funding, recommendation-letter, research-proposal

I submitted a proposal for a grant. My advisor read the first "final" version of the proposal and approved it. He really knows the project as we both have been working on it for months. Then, some collaborators read the proposal and suggested some pertinent changes, but nothing fundamental. As a result, the title changed slightly (the old and the last title are practicaly the same). I sent the new version (the version I submitted for the application) to my advisor and specified that the title changed, but I think he did not manage to read it because he was traveling to places with bad signal and he is a very busy person. Then, suddenly I received a mail confirming that my recommendation letter had been submitted. I am not sure if he noted that change. As I said, he knows exhaustively the project and my qualifications, but I am scared about that detail. If he has mistaken the title (obviously unintentional), could it be a red flag enough to reject the proposal? I read that some reviewers automatically reject a proposal if the recommendation letter has any little inaccuracy. I think that it is kind of an extreme position; however, I am not the reviewer. What do you think about it? Thanks in advance for your opinions!

Answer (score 2):

No one can say for sure but I doubt it will be an issue. People make mistakes. Other people recognize that. And the mistake wasn’t yours.

I don’t think you need to do anything but if the writer has a way to correct the error it wouldn’t hurt.

But it is what it is if nothing can be done. Relax until you know there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I can't stop thinking in the worst situations haha. But, I will try to be relax. As you said, everyone make mistakes and I hope the reviewers comprehend that.